# Items in one row but in different blocks

Tags: html, css, datatable

Have a little issue to force items to be in one row without a table. 
For example I have like this: 
Problem is if somehow long text in left block has word break (because of screen width, maybe), then two columns will not match.
I know it is easy to do with table, but is there another way to do it flexible?

html

```
<div class="data">
     <div class="data__name">
        <ul>
           <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.:</li>
           <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.:</li>
           <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.:</li>
           <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.:</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="data__line"></div>
     <div class="data__info">
        <ul>
           <li>item1</li>
           <li>item2</li>
           <li>item3</li>
           <li>item4</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```

css

```
    .data {
        font-size: 15pt;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        margin: 25px 0;
    }

    .data__name {
        color: #666666;
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -ms-flex: 0 40%;
        flex: 0 40%;
    }

    .data__line {
        border-left: 2px solid gray;
    }

    .data__info {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: 5%;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `word-break: break-word;` on li element to wrap text inside component if text is too long

```css
.data {
  font-size: 15pt;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.data__name {
  color: #666666;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 40%;
  flex: 0 40%;
}

.data__name li {
  word-break: break-word;
}

.data__line {
  border-left: 2px solid gray;
}

.data__info {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 5%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="data">
  <div class="data__name">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolorvvvvvvvvvvvv sit amet.:</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv:</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.:</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.:</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="data__line"></div>
  <div class="data__info">
    <ul>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item3</li>
      <li>item4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  flex-wrap: wrap; for the items